# How do I make button to work when holding button in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, button

I am new in Unity.

There is one cube. I want to make cube go right and left continuously.
Right now it only work when i lift my finger from the pressed button (it is 3d game).

Here is my code:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;    
    public float sidewaysforceand = 150f;
    public void rightforce()
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysforceand * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

    }
    public void leftforce()
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysforceand * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean a UI button not a key/mouse button I take it.. as this shows no button type code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place them both in the same script / Update that tracks if the buttons have been pressed.

```
public void Update()
{
    float xChange = 0;
    if(Input.GetKey(rightButton))
         xChange ++;
    if(Input.GetKey(leftButton))
         xChange --;
    rb.AddForce(sidewaysforceand * Time.deltaTime * xChange, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

If you are using UI Buttons you will have to use a flagging system such as:

```
bool rightFlag = false;
bool leftFlag = false;
public void Update()
{
    float xChange = 0;
    if(rightFlag)
         xChange ++;
    if(leftFlag)
         xChange --;
    rb.AddForce(sidewaysforceand * Time.deltaTime * xChange, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
public void EnableRightFlag() //put on button down press.
{
     rightFlag = true;
}
public void EnableLeftFlag() //put on button down press.
{
     leftFlag = true;
}
```

Then you just have to add a trigger for when the button is not pressed to set the flags back to false.